# Simple Gas Mileage

Tags: python

I am new to python and am trying to make what should be a relatively simple function.  By entering how far you have driven and how many gallons of gas you used, it will calculate your MPG.  Really it is just a division problem.  What I have so far is this:

```
dist_traveled = raw_input ("How far did your car travel? (In miles?) ")
gas_consumed = raw_input ("How much gas did you use? (In gallons)")
def efficiency():
    efficiency = dist_traveled/gas_consumed
    return efficiency
efficiency = MPG
print MPG
```

what I can't get it to do is actually divide.  I am using python 2.7.5   can someone help/walk me through this?  thanks

Comment: You have to convert the input to `float` first. Also, don't redefine the name of the function.

Comment: @tobias_k how do I do that

Comment: There are quite a few things wrong here. You haven't defined MPG anywhere, and you haven't called the function anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, the user input you get from `raw_input` is just a string. You have to convert those strings to floating point numbers, using the `float` bultin function. Also, I'd suggest changing your function so that it takes input parameters instead of using the global values. And you have to call the function properly.

Try this:

```
def efficiency(dist, gas):
    return dist/gas

dist_traveled = raw_input ("How far did your car travel? (In miles?) ")
gas_consumed = raw_input ("How much gas did you use? (In gallons)")

MPG = efficiency(float(dist_traveled), float(gas_consumed))
print MPG
```

You might also want to handle incorrect user input, i.e. when the user enters something that can not be parsed as a floating point number, e.g. using a `try/except` block and a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
def efficiency():
    dist_traveled = float(raw_input ("How far did your car travel? (In miles?) "))
    gas_consumed = float(raw_input ("How much gas did you use? (In gallons)"))
    return dist_traveled/gas_consumed
print "%.2f" % efficiency()
```